# How to install apps into android device without internet connection?

Tags: usb, installation

I have:

1. A Windows XP with internet connection.
2. The .apk file in the computer.
3. A USB cable.
4. A rooted android device with sdcard.

I do not have:

1. WiFi connection for my android device.
2. **Any file explorer app in android device.**

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `adb install full-file-name.apk` from the command line, where "full-file-name" is the name of the application you want to install.

See [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42474/is-there-a-minimal-installation-of-adb) to install ADB

Comment: An ADB Install instruction can also be found on our site: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575). While it's a good idea to have such a thing ready, for this task it's not really needed: Copying the `.apk` to the SDCard, and open it from any file explorer, does the job as well -- see the question which this one is marked as "possible duplicate" of.

Comment: A file explorer is great but the OP said they do not have one, thus needing to use the adb. And thanks for the link I will switch to that one for more internal promotion of other users content.

Comment: Oh -- I must have missed that one. Still, it's not necessarily needed. Two more options include: the web browser (using a `file:///mnt/sdcard/` URL to browse/navigate to the `.apk`), and the "Downloads" app (if the `.apk` was placed into the download folder on the card). If you want to make some extra rep, you could sum up something generic in the [installation tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/installation/info), so it's at a central place we all easy remember where to find :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the other two options. And I will work on that.

Comment: Great, thanks! Btw: I should have tried the two mentioned methods before mentioning them here. Though they sound logical, they seem not to work on all devices: stock browser on my Optimus refused to list directory contents (though another browser might do so) -- and simply copying a file to `/sdcard/Download` didn't make the "Downloads" app pick that up :(